# Expression evaluation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so while looking into basics, I came across expression evaluation so normally expression will be evaluated in the order of "Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction and others".

My Sample expression is "**2+10-19+4-90+1**"

My understanding is in the above expression first the no's will perform addition based on the priority of addition over subtraction so it will be "**12-23-91**" and the result might be "**-80**" but while checking the output of the expression it returns "**-92**".

Please explain how this result is derived and correct my understanding in evaluating an expression by the javascript engine.

Comment: It's math, and performed left-to-right just like a human would. Unrelated, but 12-23-91 would be -102, not -80.

Comment: `the priority of addition over subtraction` - where does this belief come from?

Comment: @DaveNewton - so `2 + 3 * 4` is ...?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just what you'd think (at least in JavaScript). OP's question didn't include any multiplication, did it? Nope.

Comment: look at [javascript operator precendece](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) - addition and subtraction have equal precedence ... so therefore with just those two operators present, yes, left-to-right is how it works

Comment: @DaveNewton - yes

Answer (score 2):

Addition and Subtraction have the same priority(precedence) and are performed left to right whichever occurs first.

```
=2+10-19+4-90+1
=12-19+4-90+1
=-7+4-90+1
=-3-90+1
=-93+1
=-92
```

Same follows for multiplication and division. They are performed left to right whichever occurs first.
For more examples try the ones on this page.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp

Comment: Why you guys are answering this kind of questions ? It's maths, not javascript.

Comment: That's because in programming, operator precedence plays important role. Suppose in above expressions there would be multiplication instead of minus, they would have been evaluated first and then addition would have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The priority for `+` and `-` operators are same, and it follows left to right precedence. So being at same precedence level, it gave you answer `-92` as follows:

```
2+10-19+4-90+1
=12-19+4-90+1
=-7+4-90+1
=-3-90+1
=-92
```

You could read entire operator precedence in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).